# On click of a button open an application in client side

Tags: javascript, python

My app is to open one of the applications with some parameters in Windows.
I was successful by doing that in Flask and provided .exe format and it works properly.
now instead of giving .exe I want to place the project in the server and give the URL.
the problem here is if I execute the `subprocess.popon` it tries to execute on the server but now that I want to execute on the client side.

I checked with ActiveXObject but got to know that it is just for IE.

The question is what is the best approach to do it?
by NodeJS I thought but that is also server side which is the same as Python.

Comment: You cannot execute an external program on the client side. This is due to security. You can indicate that the browser should try to open a file, such as a `.pdf`, with the default program. But it seems you want it to run a `.exe` which is impossible.

Comment: This seems to be an x y problem. You did not say what you arr actually trying to archive. But whatever you want to do, you will have to it within the capabilities and the security model of the browser. Browsers have APIs for many things nowadays.